# How to looking for cursor state view

Tags: vb.net

I make it textbox and output text.

I move to cursor successfully.

Code:

```
txtEtcInfo.SelectionStart = txtEtcInfo.TextLength
txtEtcInfo.Focus()
```

But scroll over text

I can looking cursor
I need scroll down

How to cursor state automatically scroll down??

I am not neitive speaker Understand the wind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `ScrollToCaret` method:

```
txtEtcInfo.SelectionStart = txtEtcInfo.TextLength
txtEtcInfo.Focus()
txtEtInfo.ScrollToCaret()
```